# to get the quadratic equation for a given formula

Tags: quadratics

I have a formula $A=-\frac{u'(a)}{u(a)}$ such that $u(a)=u(0)s(a)+u'(0)q(a)$ and $u'(a)=u(0)s'(a)+u'(0)q'(a)$ , I was asked to find the quadratic equation for $A$ ..

I know it means I have to find the coeffiecents $a$,$b$,and $c$ in the formula $aA^2+bA+c=0$ but I don't know how I can find them..I appreciate any help ..

Comment: Is $A$ a constant?

Comment: yes it is constant

Comment: is the equation $A=-u'(a)/u(a)$ an identity or is it only true for one specific $a$?

Comment: true for specific $a$ and $a$ here is different from the coefficient $a$ in the quadratic equation